# How to remove Comma printing at the last of the integer List?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to remove the comma from the last of the int list without using the loop but not got any solution yet.
Below is my recursive function.

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())

def printPattern(n): 

# Base case (When n becomes 0 or negative)  
    if (n == 0 or n < 0): 
        print(n, end = ", ") 
        return 
    print(n, end = ", ") 
    printPattern(n - k)  
    print(n, end = ", ")
printPattern(n)

Input: n = 12 k = 5
Output: 12, 7, 2, -3, 2, 7, 12,
Desired Output: 12, 7, 2, -3, 2, 7, 12
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove the comma from the end?

Comment: Why not only print a comma __before__ the second and subsequent values? It’s easy to not print a comma before the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the variable of n in the function, you can reference your global n and check against that, and not print the last comma.

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())

def printPattern(x):

# Base case (When n becomes 0 or negative)
    if (x == 0 or x < 0):
        print(x, end = ", ")
        return
    print(x, end = ", ")
    printPattern(x - k)
    if (x == n):
        print(x)
    else:
        print(x, end = ", ")
printPattern(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
n = int(input())
k = int(input())

def printPattern(n, level=0):
    if (n == 0 or n < 0):
        print(n, end=", ")
        return
    print(n, end=", ")
    printPattern(n - k, level + 1)
    print(n, end=", " if level else "")
printPattern(n)
printPattern(n - k)  
print(n, end = ", ")
```

printPattern(n)

Input: n = 12 k = 5
Output: 12, 7, 2, -3, 2, 7, 12,
Desired Output: 12, 7, 2, -3, 2, 7, 12